# Выборка строк с помощью значений из списка

Tags: python, pandas, excel, python-2.x, выборка

Необходимо выбрать строки которые бы не соответствовали значению из списка

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False
df = pd.read_excel(r'R:\TEST.xlsx')
s = [u'Проектируемый']
print df.loc[df[u'СТАТУС ОБЪЕКТА']!= s]
```

Выдаёт ошибку: `ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 3 vs 1`

Как правильно прописывать выборку с использованием значений из списка ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка у вас выходит потому, что если в `s` у вас список (пусть и из одного элемента), то `Pandas` не понимает, как вы хотите сравнивать два списка разного размера между собой.

Проверку на не вхождение в список нужно делать так:

```
s = [u'Проектируемый',u'Готовый',u'Приемка']
print df.loc[~df[u'СТАТУС ОБЪЕКТА'].isin(s)]
```

- `isin` - проверка на вхождение
- `~` - логическое отрицание условия

P.S. `Python 2` устарел и больше не поддерживается, переходите на `Python 3`.

Comment: @Grechkin26 Я тоже поправил, проверьте ещё раз. Хотя для `Python2` и старых версий `Pandas` не могу гарантировать, что всё будет работать.

Comment: Но если что, попробуйте и `df.loc[...]` и `df[...]` просто без `.loc`, что будет работать в старой версии `Pandas` так сразу и не знаю.